# ubuntu14.04 how to append dns permanently

Tags: dns, ubuntu-14.04

> `ubuntu14.04`

I used `dhcp` to get `ip` address and `dns`,but now I want to manipulate `dns` only (I don't wanna use `default dns`,because the `dns` server block some websites). so I modified `/etc/resolv.conf`(append： `nameserver 2001:470:20::2`) ，but when I rebooted, what I appended just gone.

so how to append `dns` permanently? thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own solution: touch a new file named `tail` under `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/` , and append the `dns` you want (e.g. `nameserver 8.8.8.8`), it works.